# Nivo Slider problem when zooming out of browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

When I was developing my own blog, I found this really weird bug on the ever popular Nivo Slider.

The problem: Whenever you zoom out the web browser, you'll get an broken image view of the slides in the nivo slider.

You can even check it out by going to their website: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/
Zoom out your web browser and you can see that the slide image looks broken.

How could I fixed this?

Thank you so much!

P.S.: If this problem would be resolved, I will try to contact the developers and give you the credit for solving this issue :D

Comment: went to their website, zoomed to the maximum my browser allows, saw nothing particular.  But I may be doing it wrong.  Can you elaborate a bit more or maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: You must be "zooming in"...Try "zooming out"..(ctrl + down-mousewheel)

Comment: Nope, no luck.... What browser and version are you using?  And could you add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Here's a screenshot..(note that it is already finished transitioning to that slide but still has cluttered boxes): http://i.imgur.com/70L0x.png

Comment: ahhh, now I see what you mean!

Comment: no, he's right, I just did it on my page because I didn't believe him and it's happening to me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the site and this problem seems limited to IE (8) and Chrome, I haven't managed to make Firefox 5 show the same artifacts.

Nivo slices up an image to perform its magic, and I suspect rounding errors become visible as lines between the "tiles" during zoom.

I think that with a slightly modified tiling algorithm that allows for a small overlap the problem can be solved, and I suggest you submit your observation to the Nivo team.

Comment: Thanks! Now atleast I understand why this bug is happening.